# How do i fix a Number Overflow with Monogame and Xamarin?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios, xamarin, monogame

I have recently installed the latest versions of OSX, Xcode, and Xamarin Monotouch on my development hardware, and I cannot get the simplest Monogame example to run properly.

This is the bouncing box example, and it crashes when the application starts, on the first initialization of a Color struct with A = 255:

```
public byte A
{
    ...

    set
    {
        this._packedValue = (this._packedValue & 0x00ffffff) | ((uint)(value << 24));
    }
}
```

This code works fine on Windows and even the iOS simulator, but when I run it on my iPad 1 (iOS 5) or iPhone 5 (iOS6), I get the exception is "System.OverflowException: Number overflow.". If I change the code to not cause an overflow:

```
set
{
    var val = (uint)value;

    var val2 = val << 24;

    this._packedValue = (this._packedValue & 0x00ffffff) | val2;
}
```

this problem goes away, but the same problem is exhibited by the R, G, and B properties as well. My intuition is that Monogame wasn't written with number overflow in mind, and there may well be countless examples of this. This must be a 'new' problem since the example code was written.

Is there some compiler switch I am missing to force it to ignore number overflows? I am using Visual Studio 2012 to deploy over the network, and under the project properties I do not see any settings relevant to this.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this, but I didn't have any success. Can you file a bug at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com with a complete test project, since this shouldn't really happen?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question and the msdn documents, you can do the whole operation inside an `unchecked` block.

```
set
{
    unchecked
    {
        this._packedValue = (this._packedValue & 0x00ffffff) | ((uint)(value << 24));
    }
}
```

However this can result in unintended consequences (negative numbers, but since you're using unsigned, I'm not sure if you start at 0 or it still throws an exception) and I've never personally used it.

Reference can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8(v=vs.110).aspx